# Where correctly allocate semaphores in C

Tags: c, pthreads, mutex, semaphore

I'm trying to solve the "producer-consumer" exercise in C.

I've the main that creates two threads (one producer and one consumer), and their access to the buffer is handled using semaphores.

My question is: which is the best practice to allocate semaphores?
At the moment I am considering two options:

1) declare the semaphores as global variables so the main and the 2 threads can globally access to them;

2) declare the semaphores inside the main and then pass their pointer to the threads.

Which solution is the best? Or do you have other solution / advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Global variables in general should be avoided. It's safer and I'd say more readable/logical in a way to declare them in main and pass them to threads through constructor or some setter method. Though what would probably be most readable is if you'd put both the buffer and the semaphore together in a struct and pass its pointer to the threads.